# Java Exception Handling - ID Number Machine

Tags: java, exception

I'm in the process of improvement my skills in Java, now I am doing some exercises of exceptions, but I am stuck in this exercise:

> ID Number Machine: Ask a user for a ID number. The correct input for a
>   id number is 10 in length and they must all be numbers.
>
> Input: 123456790 Output: correct
>
> Input: 12eer12345 Output: incorrect
>
> Input: 12345678901 Output: incorrect

I don’t know what exception use to make the program work, i know the NumberFormatException can be use to check if the string is numeric, but in general im stuck, thanks is anybody can help me.

I’m trying to make it work with the great help you give me guys, in the page where the exercises are they give you the problem some code and you have to complete that code, so far I make this code with the code they give you:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
class Challenge{ 

 public static void main(String args[]){ 
 Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in); 
 String input;
 int num; 

 System.out.println("Enter the ID number:");  
 input = scanner.next(); 
 ///{Write your code here   
 try  
  {  
    num = Integer.parseInt(input);
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    System.out.println("incorrect");
  }  

if(input.length()==10)
        System.out.println("correct");
 ///}  
} 
}
```

I’m trying to run that and when I use the number `1234567890 the` output is "correct", and if I use the string `123qwerqw` the output is "incorrect" and this is correct behaviour. But when I use `1234` the program sticks and does not show anything.

Comment: You could create your own custom. You're not restricted to the pre-made exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The NumberFormatException is the exception that is thrown if an operation is attempted using an input value that does not match the expected form.

To see if a string is actually a number, the logic is to try to parse it to an integer.
If it throws a number format exception, it cannot be converted.

If you want to be able to deal with decimal numbers, you would need to parse to a Double using Double.ParseDouble.

Using Integer.ParseInt will fail if you enter any number that is not whole.

```
 public boolean isValidNumber(String val) throws NumberFormatException {
    try {
         int i = Integer.ParseInt(val);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //you know here that you have non numeric chars
        return false;
    }


    //To check the length...
    if (val.length > 10) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

To use the isValidNumber method....

```
String myNumber = "123456";
String myNotNumber = "a small town with views of the sea";
if (isValidNumber(myNumber)) {
    System.out.Println(String.format("The number {0} is valid", myNumber).toString());
} else {
    System.out.Println(String.format("The number {0} is not valid", myNumber).toString());
}
```

The logic of this is that if the number does contain any non-numeric values, the error is thrown when we try to convert the string to an int.
We catch the error, and return false from the method.

If the string does parse to an int, we know it's all numeric (and as we're using an integer, we know it's not a decimal).

The second test deals with the length - again, we return a false if the value does not match the criteria specified. Anything longer than 10 chars is invalid, so return a false.

The final return statement can only be reached if all the preceding checks have passed.

I'm not certain this will compile straight off (I'm writing it from memory having not used Java for about 2 years), but that is the basic logic for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code working for my problem:

```
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    class Challenge{ 

     public static void main(String args[]){ 
     Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in); 
     String input;
     int num; 

     System.out.println("Enter the ID number:");  
     input = scanner.next(); 
     ///{Write your code here   
     try  
      {  
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);            
        System.out.println(input.length()==10?"correct":"incorrect");
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
        System.out.println("incorrect");
      }         
     ///}  
    }
}
```